# Secret title in Black Ops 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

My friends told me there was a secret title in Black Ops 2 that you earn from teabagging a bunch of enemies. I have been teabagging my enemies and even teammates for 3 days straight. Can someone give me a rough estimate of how long I have to keep up this?

Comment: I believe you might've been had

Comment: LMAO, i laughed so hard at your question. just keeb teabagging man, eventually you'll got what you want.

Answer (score 6):

There is no secret title for doing that.

Comment: Maybe no one found the title yet? :p

Comment: @Lyrion I think there are plenty that would get that particular title the week the game came out.  There is no shortage of teabagging... trust me.

Comment: @Lyrion the plot thickens...

Answer (score 1):

Quickly said NO there is no hidden achievement for teabagging. An quick and manageable overview of all the achievements is found [HERE](http://www.blackopsii.com/bo2/achievements-trophies/).

Ill add them in a list just in case the link ever goes down (its a very long list, for a detailed view, click the link).

**Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 Achievements**

> No Man Left Behind (20 points) – Rescue Woods.
>
> Gathering Storm (20 points) – Investigate the jungle facility.
>
> Shifting Sands (20 points) – Gather intel on Raul Menendez from Mullah
>   Rahmaan.
>
> Driven by Rage (20 points) – Take down Menendez and his operation.
>
> Waterlogged (20 points) – Gather information on Raul Menendez’
>   suspected terrorist plot.
>
> What Happens in Colossus… (20 points) – Find the Karma weapon.
>
> False Profit (20 points) – Capture Manuel Noriega and bring him to
>   justice.
>
> Deep Cover (20 points) – Capture Menendez.
>
> Sinking Star (20 points) – Interrogate Menendez.
>
> Late for the Prom (20 points) – Escort the president to the secure
>   location in downtown LA.
>
> Death from Above (50 points) – Stop Menendez once and for all.
>
> Old Fashioned (50 points) – Complete “Pyrrhic Victory”, “Old Wounds”,
>   “Time And Fate”, and “Suffer With Me” in Veteran.
>
> Futurist (50 points) – Complete all future levels in veteran.
>
> Giant Accomplishment (50 points) – Complete all challenges in Black
>   Ops II.
>
> Mission Complete (10 points) – Complete all challenges in a level.
>
> Just Gettin’ Started (10 points) – Complete 1 challenge in any level.
>
> Singapore Sling (15 points) – Successfully neutralize the SDC
>   freighter at Keppel Terminal.
>
> Desert Storm (15 points) – Successfully escort the VIPs to safety.
>
> Defender (15 points) – Successfully defend FOB Spectre from incursion.
>
> Black Ops II Master (15 points) – Complete the campaign on Hardened or
>   Veteran difficulty.
>
> Art of War (25 points) – Successfully assassinate SDC Chairman Tian
>   Zhao.
>
> Blind Date (15 points) – Successfully rescue HVI.
>
> Family Reunion (10 points) – There are two futures.
>
> Hey Good Looking (10 points) – Plastic surgery avoided
>
> Showdown (15 points) – A duel between rivals
>
> Dirty Business (15 points) – Listen and think before you shoot.
>
> Ship Shape (10 points) – Reinforcements on the way.
>
> Dead or Alive (15 points) – Jailor or executioner.
>
> Ultimate Sacrifice (15 points) – Only one can survive.
>
> Good Karma (20 points) – Crack the celerium worm.
>
> High IQ (20 points) – Collect all intel.
>
> Back in Time (10 points) – Use a future weapon in the past.
>
> Man of the People (15 points) – Stop the brutality inflicted by the
>   PDF.
>
> Gun Nut (10 points) – Complete a level with customized loadout.
>
> Ten K (15 points) – Minimum score 10k in every mission
>
> Welcome to the Club (10 points) – Reach Sergeant (Level 10) in
>   multiplayer Public Match.
>
> Welcome to the Penthouse (50 points) – Prestige once in multiplayer
>   Public Match.
>
> Big Leagues (20 points) – Win 5 multiplayer League Play games after
>   being placed in a division.
>
> Trained Up (10 points) – Win 10 multiplayer games while playing in
>   Combat Training playlists.
>
> Party Animal (10 points) – Win 10 multiplayer games while playing in
>   Party Games playlists.
>
> Tower of Babble (75 points) – In TranZit, obey the voices.
>
> Don’t Fire Until You See (30 points) – In TranZit, have all doors
>   opened without being set on fire. The Lights Of Their Eyes (5 points)
>   – In Green Run, pacify at least 10 zombies with 1 EMP.
>
> Undead Man’s Party Bus (15 points) – In TranZit, complete all
>   additions to the bus in 1 game.
>
> Dance On My Grave (5 points) – In Green Run, acquire your Tombstone.
>
> Standard Equipment May Vary (25 points) – In TranZit, acquire 4
>   different equippable items in 1 game.
>
> You Have No Power Over Me (15 points) – You Have No Power Over Me
>
> I Don’t Think They Exist (10 points) – In TranZit, kill one of the
>   denizens of the forest while it is latched onto you.
>
> Fuel Efficient (10 points) – In TranZit, use an alternative mode of
>   transportation.
>
> Happy Hour (10 points) – In TranZit, buy 2 different perks before
>   turning on the power.